# how to use an illegal character in AHK if InStr

Tags: autohotkey

I am capturing a user hotkey choice using GuiControl, hotkey then save to an ini. I then retrieve from the ini file the hotkey and use it in code. The only problem is the hotkeys with modifiers are saving as AHK shorthand, such as ^ for control, and when I try to use this in a script like so:

```
key = ^2
controlSend, ,%key%, ahk_id %id%
```

The game will only actually receive the "2". So I wrote a function to remove the ^ and replace with {LControl Down} and {LControl Up} respectively. However it will not work as the follow code throws and illegal character error in the 2nd line "IfInString, ^, input" but I also assume it will in the 4th line.

```
convertModifier(input) {
    IfInString, ^, input
    {
        output := {LControl Down} . SubStr(input, InStr(input, ^)+1) . {LControl Up}
        return output
    }
}
```

I have tried using both ` and \ to escape the ^ but to no luck. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks alot in advance I appreciate your time.

Comment: You need to flip your params, it's `IfInString, input, ^`

Answer (score 0):

So Sidola was correct, I had the needle and stack the wrong way around in my IfInString. With a few other bugs worked out, this solution began to work like a dream.

Thanks Sidola.